# run script after xserver started

Tags: bash, x-server, xinput

I have a script which I would love to run after xserver has started. This file is located at `/home/karl/.scripts/startup/sensei-raw-startup.sh`.

How to I invoke this file after xserver has started?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do. All DEs (KDE, Gnome,...) provide ways to run programs at start, for instance in KDE you can put an executable into `/home/YourName/.kde/Autostart`. This is good enough for me, the details for you depend on your DE.

**EDIT**

As suggested by @grawity in the following comment, there is a method valid for all DEs, which is to place the executable in `/home/YourName/.config/autostart`.

Alternatively, you can place an executable file in `/etc/X11/Xsession.d`, and this will be executed for **all users** of your system; for most people this is just as good as the above solutions since they are the only users of their laptop/desktop/whatever... Just remember to give this file a name starting with `99z`, so that it is executed last: the other files in the directory need to be executed before custom scripts.

Comment: The cross-DE method is [~/.config/autostart/](http://standards.freedesktop.org/autostart-spec/autostart-spec-latest.html).